# How to filter out unwanted data and noise for parabolic/polynomial polyfit in Matlab or python

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, filtering

I have a set of data that I need to find a best fit polynomial for. Currently I am using python's polyfit, but there are obvious outliers (when the value drops to 0 on the parabola) that affect my polynomial. How would I go about filtering out the unwanted drops in the data so that I get a best fit parabola that does not include the noise?

[image]

There is an obvious parabolic path that I would like to get the polynomial to.
Is there a matlab function that I could use to filter out the noise so polyfit would be a better representation of the parabolic data path?

Comment: Use [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC). Perfect case to use it.  See here for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739500/determining-regression-coefficients-for-data-matlab/30740290#30740290 - The actual function I'm fitting isn't a parabolic function, but use the concepts in the post to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter a 1D function by convolution.

I used this data set:

```
y=[0 10 50 80 100 0 100 0 110 0 130 130 0 130 0 110 0 100 0 70 0 50 20 10 0];
```

[image: Original Image]

And when convoluting with

```
ones(1,10)/10
```

like this:

```
convolved=conv(y,ones(1,10)/10);
```

and then normalizing it to the same maximal value,

```
convolved2=convolved*max(y)/max(convolved);
```

this is the result:

[image: Convolution with 10]

And when convoluting with

```
convolved=conv(y,ones(1,50)/50);
```

This is the result (again multiplied by the max of y and divided by the max of convolved):

[image: Convolution with 50]

You just need to adjust the filter the way you need. Hopes that this helps.